# How is declaring a new struct instance with "var" different from using "new" in Go?

Tags: go

The following code creates a usable instance of the struct, `Car`. How is this different than using `new(Car)`?

Example:

```
type Car struct {
  make string
}

func Main() {
  var car Car; // how is this different than "car := new(Car)"?

  car.make = "Honda"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One defines a Car variable, the other returns a pointer to a Car.

```
var car Car      // defines variable car is a Car
car2 := new(Car) // defines variable car2 is a *Car and assigns a Car to back it
```

`car := new(Car)` can be implemented in relation to `var car Car` like this:

```
var x Car
car := &x
```

Comment: `var x Car; car := &x` is also equivalent to the more idiomatic form: `car := &Car{}`

Comment: But does this change the allocation in any way, like `new` in C++ allocating on the freestore rather than the stack?

Comment: @larsmans, the spec doesn't say it does so it is compiler dependent. I believe in current implementations new always allocates to the heap and the other allocates to the stack if it can be proven the pointer does not escape the function. Either way it has no impact on the correctness of the code.