# Use of new vs var in Go

Tags: pointers, go

You have a function with an argument, a pointer to a type.

```
type bar struct{...}

func foo(arg *bar)
```

Is there any difference between:

```
var b bar
foo(&b)
```

and

```
b := new(bar)
foo(b)
```

The use of new creates an allocation.

Comment: Don't think so. This question specifically asks about the result of `&Variable` vs `new(Type)` when passed to a pointer type taking function. 10990174 doesn't ask nor answer that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no difference, as, contrary to C, Go explicitly states that you can give a pointer to a locally created variable.

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) :

> Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a
>   local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives
>   after the function returns

Answer (score 5):

Both should represent the same pointer to the same object initialized with the same default value.

The [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) does mention:

> After

```
type T struct { i int; f float64; next *T }
t := new(T)
```

> the following holds:

```
t.i == 0
t.f == 0.0
t.next == nil
```

> The same would also be true after

```
var t T
```

Also:

> Taking the address of a composite literal (§[Address operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)) generates a pointer to a unique instance of the literal's value.

```
var pointer *Point3D = &Point3D{y: 1000}
```

Answer (score 1):

One assigns a nil pointer, the other assigns a pointer to a zero initialized struct. In a linked list style example:

```
type Node struct { 
  Data int
  Next *Node
}
```

Create a node in each of the mentioned ways

```
var node1 = new(Node)
var node2 *Node
```

Printing the variables gives

```
&{0 <nil>}
<nil>
```

This means that if you were to try to do this

```
fmt.Println(node1.Data)
fmt.Println(node2.Data)
```

The first will print out 0, the second will throw a nil pointer dereference exception and panic.

Answer (score -4):

There are a differences in certain situations. `new(T)`, as the name implies, returns a, well, new instance of type T, while `var b T` is a single instance, once and forever (err, actually until end of its lifetime == going out of scope, not reachable...).

Consider this loop

```
var b bar
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    foo(&b)
}
```

vs

```
var b *bar
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    b = new(b)
    foo(b)
}
```

In the later case, if `foo` for example stores its `arg` in some container, results in 10 instances of `bar` existing while the former case with only one - in variable `b`.

Another difference is in the performance. The variable `b` would be either a fully static global variable or will typically sit at a statically known offset in some function/method invocation record (a fancy name for usually a stack frame). `new` OTOH, if not optimized out by the compiler, is a memory allocator call. Such call will cost some nonzero time. If made in a loop and not actually necessary, then it can make noticeable slowdown of some code path.

Comment: The only difference is that new() returns a pointer to a variable while var allows you to declare a variable. This answer would make sense if Go recognized the difference between stack and heap in the language. See dystroy's answer below and my own answer to another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10990287/727643

Comment: @StephenWeinberg: I stand by my answer. (Of course after I now double checked it). Please specify the perceived faults wrt the specs.

Also, please tell me what (reasonable) alternative to memory allocation is for implementing `new`. Also, please let me know which existing Go compiler(s) use that alternative. Thanks in advance.

I realize the specs don't talk about stack or heap. That doesn't rule out talking about how the implementation works, especially if it aids to understanding. See also: http://research.swtch.com/godata

Comment: @JeremyWall: It's hard to tell w/o any specific information provided. Please let me know what should be changed. I would be pleased to make the answer (more) correct.

Comment: @jnml: another way to implement new anywhere is the same thing the OP did. `var b bar; ptrb := &b`. The two ways he listed are identical according to the spec. You are allowed to talk about the implementation if you mention it is implementation dependent. However, you are wrong about the implementation. Both gc and gccgo will allocate them to the heap in both cases. In both cases the escape analysis forces them to put the variable on the heap.

Comment: While you were right about the difference between your two looping examples, they missed the point of the question. If you put the `var b bar` inside the loop in the first example, it would do the exact same thing as the second example. This is what the OP asked in the first place.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg: You're using arguments I didnt't say: _"However, you are wrong about the implementation.  Both gc and gccgo will allocate them to the heap in both cases."_, but didn't say anything contrary to that - please check it for yourself. I said there would be 1 instance ("in variable b") vs ten instances ("ten instances existing"). That says nothing if 'b' is on stack or at the heap. You lost me where you claim to know better than the OP what he was asking for.
PS: I will pretend the part about what I'm allowed to talk about and under what conditions just didn't happen, ok?

Comment: You are confused. new(T) and &T{} are the same thing. The only reason new(T) exists is because the latter form cannot be used with primitive types (e.g. int). The two code snippets are different, but that's because in the first you allocate outside the loop and in second you allocate inside the loop. It's different code, you have not answered what the OP asked, instead you have posted a misinformed and confusing answer.

Comment: @AramHăvărneanu: The confusions lies in the fact that composite literals, nor in the form &T{}, were ever asked/discussed/mentioned/answered in this question by anyone before you ;-)

Comment: These programs have the same meaning (and with the current gc implementation even the same output): http://play.golang.org/p/gOpM50iBxj and http://play.golang.org/p/cIKNn3jPXV . Please don't confuse and mislead begginers by answering questions they did not ask.

Comment: @AramHăvărneanu: It's not me who is answering the non asked &T{} stuff ;-) Before your comment it was presented nowhere here. The OP didn't asked about it, no one answered about it and no one mentioned it and no one discussed taking address of a composite literal. Taking address of a variable is a different thing than &T{}.

Comment: Is there a reason you kept `is a single instance, once and forever (err, actually until end of its lifetime == going out of scope, not reachable...).` in? It seems you noticed what you wrote was not entirely correct and put further information into parenthesis. IMHO it is confusing now. Do you mind taking that bit of information out? I’d end that sentence straight after `is a single instance`.

Comment: @Kissaki: The text in parenthesis is a reminder about the limited lifetime of some things (in Go). Maybe the formulation is bad stylistically, but it's my (relaxed) style and there's nothing factually incorrect in the making-it-more-precise content of the parenthesized text. Actually, when I learn something, I prefer to firstly see the broader overview/concept with detailed specifics/exceptions/domain/limitations/... following only later/after that. Because in the opposite order it's too easy to miss the forest because of the trees ;-)

Comment: Reading the sentence again, the differences it points out are not there. Yes new returns a new instance of type T, but so does var b T. You are trying to compare the functionality of the new operator with a variable type. - Well, I’d rephrase the entire first paragraph, but keep it if you have to.

Comment: @Kissaki: This whole thread is really interesting. It seems to me that, for some reason unknown to me, the opening, scope setting **"There are a differences in certain situations."** (followed by the depiction of two such examples) is probably invisible to others ;-) (Quoted above includes the typo as originally made - the extra 'a' before the word 'differences')

Comment: jnml, Go decides whether to put data on the heap by performing escape analysis. It has nothing to do with whether they use new or not. If a pointer escapes the function then go puts that data on the heap. There is zero difference between using new(T) and &T{}.

Comment: @JeremyWall: Perhaps read the answer more carefully? Once again this is arguing by what isn't in the (allegedly wrong because of that) answer. Actually I said _"new OTOH, **if not optimized out by the compiler**, is a memory allocator call."_ which is 1) true in both gc and gccgo 2) not in **any** conflict with _"Go decides whether to put data on the heap by performing escape analysis"_. (yes, escape analysis (may, where feasible) provide information both for when an entity _must_ go to the heap as when entity doesn't have to even when introduced by `new`.) ... to be continued ...

Comment: ... Also _you're__ completely wrong about _"There is **zero difference** between using new(T) and &T{}.", as for `type T int` it has a quite **non-zero** difference in that the compiler rejects it. The `&T{}` topic was never mentioned/considered by anyone before Aram, so its discussion is absolutely irrelevant to the correctness of this answer. Which I still stand by because every single accusation of its incorrectness so far has been shown as wrong so as is this latest of yours. No offense intended, we're just searching truth, aren't we? ;-)

Comment: var b T is also a memory allocation call. The only difference between new(b) and var b T is that one is a pointer type while the other is not. In the context of what the user is asking this difference is immaterial. To phrase it differently `new(T)` and `var b T; &b` are equivalent in every way that matters including how the memory is allocated. You never address the primitive type case which as you accurately identify is the only difference between new and the & operator. Your answer reads in such a way as to be misleading as illustrated by the length of this comment thread.